# openfoam openmpi error: libmpi.so.0 not found

Tags: openmpi, openfoam

Whenever I try to compile a solver in openfoam, I get the error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libmpi.so.0, needed by /opt/openfoam211/platforms/linux64GccDPOpt/lib/openmpi-system/libPstream.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libopen-rte.so.0, needed by /opt/openfoam211/platforms/linux64GccDPOpt/lib/openmpi-system/libPstream.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libopen-pal.so.0, needed by /opt/openfoam211/platforms/linux64GccDPOpt/lib/openmpi-system/libPstream.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/opt/openfoam211/platforms/linux64GccDPOpt/lib/openmpi-system/libPstream.so: undefined reference to `MPI_Waitall'
/opt/openfoam211/platforms/linux64GccDPOpt/lib/openmpi-system/libPstream.so: undefined reference to `MPI_Abort'
/opt/openfoam211/platforms/linux64GccDPOpt/lib/openmpi-system/libPstream.so: undefined reference to `ompi_mpi_double'
/opt/openfoam211/platforms/linux64GccDPOpt/lib/openmpi-system/libPstream.so: undefined reference to `MPI_Get_count'
/opt/openfoam211/platforms/linux64GccDPOpt/lib/openmpi-system/libPstream.so: undefined reference to `MPI_Init'
/opt/openfoam211/platforms/linux64GccDPOpt/lib/openmpi-system/libPstream.so: undefined reference to `MPI_Probe'
/opt/openfoam211/platforms/linux64GccDPOpt/lib/openmpi-system/libPstream.so: undefined reference to `MPI_Send'
/opt/openfoam211/platforms/linux64GccDPOpt/lib/openmpi-system/libPstream.so: undefined reference to `MPI_Allreduce'
/opt/openfoam211/platforms/linux64GccDPOpt/lib/openmpi-system/libPstream.so: undefined reference to `ompi_mpi_packed'
/opt/openfoam211/platforms/linux64GccDPOpt/lib/openmpi-system/libPstream.so: undefined reference to `MPI_Buffer_detach'
/opt/openfoam211/platforms/linux64GccDPOpt/lib/openmpi-system/libPstream.so: undefined reference to `MPI_Bsend'
/opt/openfoam211/platforms/linux64GccDPOpt/lib/openmpi-system/libPstream.so: undefined reference to `ompi_mpi_byte'
/opt/openfoam211/platforms/linux64GccDPOpt/lib/openmpi-system/libPstream.so: undefined reference to `MPI_Irecv'
/opt/openfoam211/platforms/linux64GccDPOpt/lib/openmpi-system/libPstream.so: undefined reference to `MPI_Recv'
/opt/openfoam211/platforms/linux64GccDPOpt/lib/openmpi-system/libPstream.so: undefined reference to `ompi_mpi_comm_world'
/opt/openfoam211/platforms/linux64GccDPOpt/lib/openmpi-system/libPstream.so: undefined reference to `MPI_Get_processor_name'
/opt/openfoam211/platforms/linux64GccDPOpt/lib/openmpi-system/libPstream.so: undefined reference to `MPI_Test'
/opt/openfoam211/platforms/linux64GccDPOpt/lib/openmpi-system/libPstream.so: undefined reference to `MPI_Isend'
/opt/openfoam211/platforms/linux64GccDPOpt/lib/openmpi-system/libPstream.so: undefined reference to `MPI_Finalize'
/opt/openfoam211/platforms/linux64GccDPOpt/lib/openmpi-system/libPstream.so: undefined reference to `ompi_mpi_op_sum'
/opt/openfoam211/platforms/linux64GccDPOpt/lib/openmpi-system/libPstream.so: undefined reference to `MPI_Buffer_attach'
/opt/openfoam211/platforms/linux64GccDPOpt/lib/openmpi-system/libPstream.so: undefined reference to `MPI_Comm_size'
/opt/openfoam211/platforms/linux64GccDPOpt/lib/openmpi-system/libPstream.so: undefined reference to `MPI_Comm_rank'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I guess the problem is with the installation of open-mpi. How can I check/fix the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, check that you really have Open MPI installed.

Secondly, check that OpenFOAM is properly set to use Open MPI: see corresponding options in `etc/bashrc` (or `etc/cshrc`). Also make sure you have set any needed environment variables for Open MPI (I do not have any experience with Open MPI, I build with Intel MPI, and there are some environment variables to be set by manually calling some script).

Thirdly, check the link command lines issued by `wmake` to build your solver, *and* to build `libPstream` (during the main OpenFOAM build process). If it does not print the link line, edit `wmake/Makefile` to make it print out. Some of these lines (I think `libPstream`'s) should feature some link options and most probably paths related to Open MPI.